# Template deduction with some user-supplied arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, deduction-guide

Suppose there is a class with two template parameters

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class C {
  C(B::X x) {}
};
```

is it possible to have a deduction guide where only one of the parameters is inferred and the other is user-specified?

```
template<typename A, typename D>
C(D) -> C<A, D::Y>;
```

When I try this, clang gives me "deduction guide template contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced"

Comment: The simple answer is no.

Comment: The longer answer is that CTAD is explicitly disabled the moment you add template arguments. `C<D> c(whatever);` **will not** do CTAD. If you don't have a viable default argument, you are out of luck. Your problem is solved with a factory function, something like the `make_*` functions in the standard library.